# How can I allow other computers to use my local SOCKS SSH tunnel?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, proxy, socks

I often use an SSH tunnelling on my computer, using a SOCKS proxy.

```
ssh -D 1234 example.com
```

However, this only accepts local connections. I would like other systems on my network to be able to use the proxy on my computer as well.

How can I achieve this? If SSH doesn't have an option itself I imagine it might be possible to have a program proxy the proxy on a different port, but I don't know if there are any common tools to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tell it to bind to an external address instead of `localhost`.

```
ssh -D 192.168.0.123:1234 example.com
```

Comment: Or you can use `ssh -D "*:1234" example.com` to bind to all addresses.

Comment: I found that last comment super useful!

Comment: I used 0.0.0.0 as ip address. 

  **ssh -D 0.0.0.0:1234 example.com**

Comment: or use `-g` to bind to 0.0.0.0 (accepts all IP addresses)

Comment: so which ip and port should set on other computers to use proxy?

Answer (score -2):

You would have to enable routing on your host and set up a routing protocol, such as RIP. Basically, you have to act like a router and the other hosts have to have routing entries to get to the network on the other side (which is hopefully not a duplicate RFC1918 network).

Comment: The users just have to enter your proxy server's IP address... no routing required.

Comment: @mehaase You are confused. And what will the proxy server do with it then? How will the users reach other networks?

Comment: Through the proxy? Isn't that the whole point? ssh -D acts as a SOCKS proxy, not just a point-to-point tunnel. It's application aware.

Comment: Actually the question is confusing. I saw the tunneling, which is different from proxying. To share an IP tunnel is no different than routing through a point to point link.